# Cast a variable of filtering_istream type to ifstream type?

Tags: c++, boost, casting, iostream, ifstream

I am using the filetering_istream type to save the information in a decompressed file while using 'boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp'. But I want to cast it into the ifstream type. It there any way to do it? Great thanks!

The code is as follows:

```
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp> 
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main(){    
    std::ifstream file("test_data.dat.gz");

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;

    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());

    in.push(file);

    /* add code to convert filtering_istream 'in' into ifstream 'pfile' */

    /* It seems that the following code returns a pointer NULL */

    // std::ifstream* pfile = in.component<std::ifstream>(1); 

    return 0;

}
```

After trying boost::ref and boost::wrapper proposed by zett42, the ifstream really works. The only problem is that it doesn't give the phrases wanted.

In my text of .gz file, I wrote:

```
THIS IS A DATA FILE!
8 plus 8 is 16
```

But using the ifstream, I got:

```
is_open: 1
```

`\213<\373Xtest_data.dat\361\360V"G\307G7OWE.\205\202\234\322b\205\314bC3.\327+>\314$`

I am not sure what happened here, and can I do something to recover it?

Comment: If you are using the `ifstream`, you will read the *compressed* data. Maybe I misunderstood your problem completely. If you want to read the uncompressed data, you simply read from `in`. No need to "cast" anything then.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference of [`filtering_stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html):

> filtering_stream derives from std::basic_istream, std::basic_ostream
>   or std::basic_iostream, depending on its Mode parameter.

So no, you can't cast a `filtering_stream` directly to an `ifstream` because there is no inheritance relationship between the two.

What you can do instead, if your filter chain ends with a device that is an `ifstream`, you can grap that device by calling [`filtering_stream::component()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html#component). For streams this function returns a `boost::iostreams::detail::mode_adapter` (you can see the type by calling `in.component_type(1)`).

It's propably not a good idea to depend on an internal boost type (indicated by namespace "detail") which could change with next boost version, so one workaround is to use `boost::reference_wrapper` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp> 
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/core/ref.hpp>

int main(){    
    std::ifstream file("test_data.dat.gz");

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;

    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());

    in.push(boost::ref(file));

    if( auto pfile = in.component<boost::reference_wrapper<std::ifstream>>( 1 ) )
    {
        std::ifstream& rfile = *pfile;
        std::cout << "is_open: " << rfile.is_open() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for this inspiration, but it seems that pfile is a NULL pointer, causing a segmentation fault if I want to print the contents Inside. Do you have an idea about that? I am sure that the 'in' is correct, because I can output the contents Inside using the getline function. Great thx!

Comment: @hyoukai Could you add a code sample to your question?

Comment: Thx for your attention. Code has been added. Great thx if you can offer me some ideas!

Comment: Otherwise, I Wonder if it's possible to convert istream into ifstream? Thx

Comment: @hyoukai I had a misconception about `component()` method which is now fixed. See updated code.

Comment: Great thx, the ifstream works, which is quite amazing but seems to transform the data into other expressions. I updated the question. Could you please explain a little bit about that? I would like to fix that! Thx!